# How to make it wokr dvb-t usb a867 on kernel 3.13.3

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, dvb-t

I have kernel 3.13.3 and dvb-t usb tuner a867 based on chip af9035. What can I do to make this tuner work on kernel 3.13.3?

---

I found original driver on website avermedia but no luck with compile on kernel 3.13.3. I still have error 2 :/ Any tips?

Comment: What does the kernel say ('dmesg | tail') when you plug it in?

Comment: 'dmesg | tail' say: usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci

Comment: This seems to be part of the log. But if it is just that, the kernel recognized very few about the device (besides it is a usb device!). What is the output of 'lsusb'?

Comment: 'lsusb' say: Bus 003 Device 002: ID 07ca:0337 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc. A867 DVB-T dongle

Comment: The original driver from avermedia functions unstable as it is here (http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices). It seems the only way is to correct the 'error 2' you are having in the compilation on kernel 3.13.3.

Comment: Ok, I solved this problem with build driver from linuxtv and edit two files responsed for identifying my card. Now it work's :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same card and I had the same problem. Furtunatelly I was successful to update [old original driver from AverMedia](http://avertv.avermedia.com/Support/DownloadCount.aspx?FDFId=5653) 
You can download the patch from [here](http://uloz.to/xwD9Sv76/ap867-v1-0-29-patch). Yeasterday I found small problem in Makefile the corret line is `ifneq (,$(wildcard $(KSRC)/drivers/media/dvb/.))` not `ifeq (...`

1. Extract the original driver and you copy the patch file inside the folder.
2. Apply the patch `patch -p1 -i a867_v1.0.29.patch`
3. Repair the line `ifneq (,$(wildcard $(KSRC)/drivers/media/dvb/.))` in Makefile
4. Before you can successfully compile you must install kernel-headers and kernel-source 
   `` sudo apt-get install linux-source
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` 
   cd /usr/src
   tar -xjvf linux-source-XYZ ``
5. The driver expect symbolic link `` /lib/modules/`uname -r`/source ``
   `` ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-XYZ /lib/modules/`uname -r`/source ``

   I think maybe the source file would not be necessary If you will modify the $(KSRC) variable in makefile pointing to `headers`. I did not tested this.
6. Than you should compile
   `make
   make install`
7. If everything will go right, you will get `a867.ko` module driver which will be copied into the `` /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/usb/dvb-usb `` folder

I wrote simillar manual [here](http://www.abclinuxu.cz/hardware/pridavne-karty/televizni-karty/dvb-t/usb/-07ca-0337-avermedia-a867-dvb-t-dongle-2) (in Czech) how to get this card working. If I will find some other problems I will update the information there.
I wish you and all others good luck with this card. I hope this information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The original drivers (v1.0.29) don't work and I created a new patch following Martin's suggestions.

Therefore to install the driver:

1. Download the [original drivers](http://avertv.avermedia.com/Support/DownloadCount.aspx?FDFId=5653) and extract them
2. Download the patch from [here](https://github.com/amenychtas/a867/blob/master/a867_drv_v1.0.29.patch) and copy it in the same folder
3. Apply patch

`patch -p1 -i a867_v1.0.29.patch`

4. Install the linux sources

`sudo apt-get install linux-source-'uname -r'`

and extract them

`cd /usr/src`

`tar xfvj linux-source-XYZ`

5. Make a symbolic link to /lib/modules/'uname -r'/source using

`ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-XYZ /lib/modules/'uname -r'/source`

6. Compile

`make`

7. Install

`sudo make install`

8. Load the module using

`sudo modprobe a867`

Good luck!